# MVC - show or hide (div) field dependent on drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

we have a drop down list that if you choose "Unsatisfactory" then a Retention field should show up. We are using MVC 5 It is not working here is what we have:

Drop down:

```
List<SelectListItem> satisfactionLevel = new List<SelectListItem>();
satisfactionLevel.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "Satisfactory",
    Value = "Satisfactory"
});
satisfactionLevel.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "Unsatisfactory",
    Value = "Unsatisfactory",
});
```

The fields:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">

           <div id="QPerformance" class="form-group row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QPerformance, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div  class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.QPerformance, satisfactionLevel, "----Select----")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QPerformance, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="QRetention" class="form-group" style="visibility: hidden">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QRetention, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QRetention, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QRetention, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    }
```

The JavaScript section, this part we can't get the field to show or hide when we change the drop down:

```
  @section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function hideOnLoad() {
            $('#QRetention').hide();
        });


        $(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#QPerformance').change(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() != 'Unsatisfactory') {
                        $('#QRetention').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#QRetention').show();
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
        }
```

Comment: Can you post plain HTML you see on screen , Copy from view source that would be easy..

Comment: You have invalid html with 2 elements with `id="id="QPerformance"` and 2 elements with `id="QRetention" (the enclosing `<div>` element and the `<select>` element)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is: Razor rendered your `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.QPerformance)` element the same id with its parent `div` element.
Then js will not work correctly.

You can change your `div` id to solve it.

```
<div id="QPerformanceGroup" class="form-group row">

<div id="QRetentionGroup" class="form-group" >
```

And js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if($('#QPerformance').val() != 'Unsatisfactory')
        {
            $('#QRetentionGroup').hide();
        }

        $('#QPerformance').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != 'Unsatisfactory') {
                $('#QRetentionGroup').hide();
            } else {
                $('#QRetentionGroup').show();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("change","#QPerformance",function () {
    if ($(this).val() != 'Unsatisfactory')
       $('#QRetention').hide();
    else 
       $('#QRetention').show();
});
```

Comment: It would be highly recommended to add some explanations of the code you have posted. Simply providing sample code is not the best method to learning programming, and will not benefit the post creator as much as it would if how  and why the code was explained. A well-detailed answer will establish your credibility in the community, and your answers will attract up-votes.